# Result Validator is always nothing, how do I get it with message with prop?

Tags: .net, vb.net, validation

I have a model like that:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class Product

    Private _id As Integer
    Private _name As String
    Private _description As String
    Private _unitPrice As Decimal

    <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False)>
    Public Property Title() As String

    <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False)>
    Public Property Id() As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Description() As String
        Get
            Return _description
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _description = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property UnitPrice() As Decimal
        Get
            Return _unitPrice
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            _unitPrice = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

And my code to validate:

```
Dim results As List(Of ValidationResult) = Nothing
Dim product As New Product
If Validator.TryValidateObject(product, New ValidationContext(product), results, True) Then
    MessageBox.Show(123)
Else
    MessageBox.Show(results.ToString())
End If
```

My questions are:

1. Why is the `results` variable always `Nothing` and how can I get the error message from `result` and know which property has an error?
2. Why can `Title()` be validated but `Id()` cannot? And how can I make `Id()` validated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the `results` variable always `Nothing` and how can I get the error message from `result` and know which property has an error?

When the `validationResults` parameter is null, the validation stops at the first error and no errors are added to the collection. If you want it to hold a collection of failed validations, you must initialize the collection before passing its reference:

```
Dim results As New List(Of ValidationResult)
```

> Why can `Title()` be validated but `Id()` cannot? And how can I make `Id()` validated?

`Title` is a String, which is a *reference* type whose default value is null (AKA, `Nothing`), while `Id` is an Integer, which is a *value* type whose default value is 0. So, the `RequiredAttribute` makes no sense here since the property will always have a value. You may change its type to a `Nullable(Of Integer)` if you want it to work with the `RequiredAttribute`:

```
Public Property Id As Integer?
```

Comment: sorry, how do I get prop name of ValidationResult? example Title, Id where error has. I can see ValidationResult.MemberNames but its an IEnumerable im not sure this is only one value.

Comment: @May'Habit Yes, `MemberNames` should only contain one value in this case.

Comment: When does it contain multi value? I remember i met this once

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3464065/8967612).